# py2exe doesn't include entire package

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am trying to build an exe file using py2exe. The script is to create some word clouds using pytagcloud.

The issue is that py2exe doesn't include the entire pytagcloud package because of which the exe doesn't work. What I mean by this is that in Lib\site-packages, pytagcloud contains two folders fonts and lang. However, after building the exe when I check the build, the fonts folder is missing. The exe itself gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordcloud.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "pytagcloud\__init__.pyc", line 25, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\dist\\wordcloud.exe\\pytagcloud\\fonts\\fonts.json'
```

I've been stuck at this for over 8 hours! I'm totally frustrated now! I would highly appreciate any help!

I am using Win 7, Python 2.7.3 and Pytagcloud 0.3.5

Comment: You may need to add those to the includes you pass to py2exe, or look into adding data files.

Comment: I tried including the package pytagcloud but it still leaves out that one folder. Oh and I also tried PyInstaller and cx_freeze unsuccessfully!